# "docker build": cannot find 'make' even though already installed

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to create a docker image on MacOS using the below command. Note **docker build** cannot run *any* command, I tried it with **npm --version**, and it couldn't find **npm** either.

```
% docker build -<<EOF 
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD node /app/index.js
EOF
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
[output clipped...]
=> ERROR [3/3] RUN make /app                                                                                                
------
> [3/3] RUN make /app:
#11 0.200 /bin/sh: 1: make: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c make /app]: exit code: 127
```

However, make is already installed, via **xcode-select**:

```
% /bin/sh -c make /app
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Can anyone help me here please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker can't use software installed on the host. You need to install `make` in your Dockerfile like this

```
% docker build -<<EOF 
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD node /app/index.js
EOF
```

Comment: Got it. I ended up not needing make, as the dockerfile I posted was a sample, but thanks anyways!